# CCParticleExplosion color?

Tags: colors, cocos2d-iphone

I realize that a ccColor3B takes RGB values between 0 and 255, but in a ccColor4F, the values are between 0 and 1.0? I have custom colors I would like to use something like `ccColor3B blueColor = ccc3(61, 66, 255);` as a ccColor4F. I've tried dividing by 255 but all of the colors show up as black for some reason. My code looks something like:    `ccColor4F startColor;

    startColor.r = blueColor/255;
    startColor.g = blueColor/255;
    startColor.b = blueColor/255;
    startColor.a = 1.0f;`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deal with each RGB value individually.  For example:

`startColor.r = blueColor.r / 255.0f;`

Or you could just use what's already in place to do that conversion.

From `ccTypes.h`:

`static inline ccColor4F ccc4FFromccc3B(ccColor3B c)`